# cross-Domain request with download progress bar

Tags: jquery, ajax, download, cross-domain, progress-bar

I want to show download progress bar with cross-domain request ajax jquery.I am downloading my .js file from other domain with ajax and for this I want to show download statuts.My file size is up to 4MB. Also want to know if there is other way to achieve.I want to do it with pure html

Comment: XHR supports both download and upload progress.  Have a look on SO or google for examples. This has been covered many times already.

Comment: Yeah,you are right,XHR supports both download and upload progress,but when I set crossDomain:true in $.ajax download progress bar not shown,I've used xhr field,but that code is not excuted with crossDomain:true

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AJAX is one request, one response, so I would say the simple answer is that you can't. If you were able to write the bytes as they come back to a file, you could http request the download file for it's size and make a widget showing the size of the file / the size you have written.

However, because your response activity on the AJAX request will not be fired until the entire response is received (aka the whole file), I would say there isn't a way to do it unless you can request separate parts in AJAX (which A: I don't think you can, and B: would not be a good idea because it is asynchronous and could result in file data being out of order).

I would suggest writing a service method in Java using their socket API and requesting "ranges" of the file in http requests, and making subsequent calls to that service for each piece of the file, and updating the status bar as you get responses from your service.